# Exchange Data Between Two rails applications

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-2, rails-postgresql

I have two applications App A(rails 2.2.2) and App B(rails2.3.11) and both resides in Heroku.
App B is the Upgraded Version(in terms of functionality) of App A.I have some models(say 4) which are similar in context(but their associations varies), now I need to exchange the data when the User clicks on the "migrate to new system" from App A(As such in Orkut, Gmail). So,that he should get all the data associated with his login and need to be saved in the App B database.

I have used Active Record establish connection but it is not switching to the default database after posting the data.

I am new bee to rails. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have gone through the dbcharmer and Magic multiconnections but they are only useful for rails>3. Every one is suggesting AR.establish connection for rails<3 versions.The dbcharmer gem is useful for the Mysql it seems and for the postgres there is no such usage.

Comment: I am trying to connect to other database with the configuration available at heroku.But we need to get request and responses as  such they are saved or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use active record.establish_connection method to switch b/w two DB in Rails
if you have the details of the Two Db's.

Here some code.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "postgres",
  :host     => "host",
  :username => "myuser",
  :password => "mypass",
  :database => "somedatabase"
)
```